# Optional Query Firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

While using Angular Firestore we can use optional queries like this:

```
this.afs.collection(this.databaseCollection, ref => { return query ? query : ref; })
```

Is there something like this for the Admin SDK (firestore) as well? Or do I need to create a separate function for every query?

I would like to have one method (like above) where we can get all the documents in the collection if there is no query given, otherwise use the query.

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: It says that I can only have one parameter for the collection method. But that means that for every action I have to have a method. I would like to have one method that does a call with a optional parameter. It says that the ref can not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to create a method that can take both a Query and a Collection as its argument.

In that case it helps to realize that the [`CollectionReference` class](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/CollectionReference) extends the `Query` class. From the linked docs:

> ## CollectionReference
>
> *CLASS*
>
> A `CollectionReference` object can be used for adding documents, getting document references, and querying for documents (using the methods inherited from [`Query`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Query.html)).
>
> **Extends**
>
> [`Query`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Query.html)

So if you create a method signature that accepts a `Query`, you can also pass a `CollectionReference` to it.